# Noob - API getting stuck in a simple GET (express,node)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

In trying to build my first express API, I am encountering many problems. I am following some simple guide on youtube, and his code works (FOR HIM). When I try it with Postman, I simply get nothing, but it appears to be in some kind of loop (because I handle the errors)

I have checked that my route is ok, and tried experimenting with next() (which seems like I don't need it just yet)

Player is my model made with Mongoose

```
app.get("/players/:id", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Player.findById(id)
      .exec()
      .then(doc => {
        console.log("From database", doc);
        if (doc) {
          res.status(200).json(doc);
        } else {
          res
            .status(404)
            .json({ message: "No valid entry found for provided ID" });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: err });
      });
});
```

So when trying a GET in Postman on:

http://localhost:3000/players/5cf66338f00c424494316eb2

I get a loading screen, and after some time "There was an error connecting to...".

[image: Postman request & response]

Any help/tips/solution/insights are appreciated!

Comment: Could you please add screens of your postman request and response to the question?

Comment: @Div done, though it does not show much

Comment: Check this setting must be off: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckdqa.png

Comment: Are you sure the application is running?

Comment: @Div apparently I was using the wrong app. Now I downloaded the latest PM and ticked the setting off, it didn't work (thanks anyway!)
and yes MattB : https://imgur.com/a/T2hgr9W

Comment: @Div that was because I typed node index.jsµ ('µ'). Note that after that, I put in the right command and my index.js does run. No error here

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the information, could you publish your code at some where..? I'll run on my machine and check.@ArthurP

Comment: @Div I put the files in a github repo:
https://github.com/Ferbie/SBProject/tree/master/SBProject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your repo is up-to-date, then you are not connecting your app with your database.
Add the following code in your app replacing the database with your own database:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```